# What is the purpose of new() while declaration of a generic class?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

What is the purpose of new() while declaration of BaseEntityCollection class?
If I'm going to remove it, I got an error with the following message "T must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter ..."

```
public abstract partial class BaseEntityCollection<T> : 
       List<T> where T : BaseEntity, new()
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It means that whatever class you specify for `T`, it has a default (no parameters) constructor.

Therefore, in the generic class, you can do `new T()` and it will create a new object of type T.

Answer (score 5):

Writing `new()` forces the parameter to have a default constructor.

Without it, you can't write `new T()`.
Your error happens when you try to pass a non-`new()` type as a `new()`'d parameter.

---

Also, [do not inherit `List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182142.aspx).
Instead, you should inherit [`Collection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132397.aspx), which is designed for inheritance.

Comment: If I am going to use Collectiion<T>, how can I create a new collection object which inherits from Collection<T>?

Answer (score 1):

The type `T` has to have a parameterless constructor. This enables you to create new instances by doing `var t = new T()` which would be impossible otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

It is the notation for the **generic constraint**: Must have (public) parameterless constructor.

Answer (score 1):

This means that your generic type has to have parameterless constructor.

```
BaseEntityCollection<T> : List<T>
```

I am not sure what are you doing here, but I think it is against Liskov's rule. Check your hierarchy.

[Constraints on Type Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

That is one of the possible "generic type constraints" you can associate with your generic type.  Using the constraint "new()" will only allow you to use a generic type if it has a parameterless constructor.  This can be useful for things like serialization, or factory-type methods, where you need to create an object of type T.

Here are some other generic type constraints:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

It's a generic constraint. In this case, it's a the [new Constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).